# Reducing indeterminates with basis of maximal ideal in polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $F$ be a field and consider the ring $R=F[x_1,...,x_n]$.
Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Then for all indeterminates $x_j,j=1,...,n$, there exists some $k$ and some $\alpha_{i_1,\cdots,i_n},i_j=1,\cdots,k-1$ such that:

$$x_i^k=\sum_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}\alpha_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}+q$$
where $q\in I$.

Is this true? If it is not, how can I find a counterexample? If it is, how can I prove it? I was thinking of choosing a Gröbner basis for $I$, but it's a bit messy when I have to choose the order of terms.

Does $I$ need to be maximal? Can we weaken the hypothesis, like "$I$ can be an ideal of the form $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I))$ or a prime ideal"?

Note that for $n=1$, it's the same as saying there exists some $k$ such that

$$x^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\alpha_i x^i+q$$
where $q\in I$ and this is what I'm trying to generalize.

Comment: You're sure you don't want to allow mixed monomials like $x_1x_2$ and so on?

Comment: @Hoot I don't want. But if it's necessary I will have to allow them.

Comment: And now that I think so, yes, it's necessary.

Comment: By Hilbert Nullstellensatz, one has $x_i^k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\alpha_jx_i^j+q$ with $q\in I, \alpha_j\in F$, $I$ being a maximal ideal. I am not sure I understood your question.

Comment: @Mohan How do we use the Nullstellensatz when $F$ is not algebraically closed?

Maybe you mean some weak form of the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says that the extension $F\to F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ where $I$ is a maximal ideal is a finite extension.

Comment: Oh, that's true. But even if it's true, how can you say that the $k-$th power of $x_i$ is given by a linear combination of the previous powers of that indeterminate (Plus the element of the ideal)? From $R/I$ being a finite extension the linear combination would need other indeterminates, and even elements of the form $x_1x_2$, as Hoot says (Since the generators of $R/I$ include these products). In any case, this form og the Nullstellensatz is what I need. Thanks.